# Trying to find the miminum and max value of an array with pointers

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to find the minimum and maximum value of a given array with a size as a parameter and pointers for the min and max values. What am I doing wrong?

```
void FindMinMax(const int array[], int size, int* min, int* max)
{
    int minVal = array[0];
    int maxVal = array[0];
    int i;
    
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxVal) {
            *max = array[i];
        }
        if (array[i] < minVal) {
            *min = array[i];
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I tried inputting the size into the array in a new declaration, but that didn't work and said it couldn't be defined.

Comment: You don't need the local variables `minVal` and `maxVal`. Anyway, if you want to use them, you need to also update them when you update `*max` or `*min`.

Comment: As-written, you're computing the last element in the array that's greater than array[0] and the same for less than.

Comment: Minor bug: code will fail if size is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minVal` and `maxVal` are not updated during the loop, so the comparisons are only ever made against the first element of the array. This means `*min` and `*max` will simply be the *last* value in the array greater than / less than the first element, not necessarily the *largest* value or *smallest* value overall.

The local variables are redundant.

```
void FindMinMax(const int array[], int size, int *min, int *max)  
{             
    if (size > 0)            
        *min = *max = array[0];
                          
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {   
        if (array[i] > *max)           
            *max = array[i];
        else if (array[i] < *min)           
            *min = array[i];            
    }                                   
}
```

Comment: Notes: the second `if` can be an `else if`, and `size` should probably be of type `size_t`.

Comment: Also has OP's original, minor bug: code will fail if size is 0.

Comment: @Chris Good point on `else if`. I usually avoid changing function signatures though, as they are often a hard requirement for whatever grading is taking place.

Comment: @jarmod Added a check, but it does beg the question of usability when `size < 1`. Caller must take care to ensure `*min` and `*max` are not indeterminate.

Comment: @jarmod an array with size 0 would be inviting UB anyway, no?

Comment: Some future caller of this function could have an int[10] array and want to find the min/max among the first N elements of that array where 0 <= N <= 10. I know it's a edge case, but seems simple to firewall it anyway.

Comment: @jarmod In that case, the calling code would need special handling for a zero-sized array, as the function has no way to indicate the `*min` and `*max` values have not been updated.

Comment: @AndrewHenle correct, that's a follow-on problem with the code. Anyhow, I did indicate that it was likely a minor issue.

Comment: @Oka Leaving `*min, *max` alone when `size <= 0` is a good choice.  Caller could set them to `INT_MAX, INT_MIN` and test for a wrong ordered `min, max`.

Comment: "The local variables are redundant." They aren't, since they can give significantly improved performance. Updating values through a pointer continuously is slow on most ISA and might not be ideal in terms of cache either. Consider https://godbolt.org/z/93csqedx8. My "fixed" version of the OP's code results in some x86 SIMD orgy which I'm not the right person to untangle, whereas your version here leads to more conventional machine code. I dare not guess which version that performs best in actual benchmarking, but I wouldn't just dismiss the use of local variables.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks, but I'm not really sure what an actually useful alternative to leaving them alone would be - one that has less overhead than *not* calling the function (i.e., the caller could just as easily test for `size <= 0`). A use case I could quickly think of for *unconditionally* calling this function with a zero-size, would be grabbing the min/max of a fluctuating data set, that occasionally has zero elements, in which case the *previously* held values would persist. But again, that's pure convenience, as the caller could still avoid the call with the same conditional.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, but while that is interesting to note, none of it is important to realise the algorithm at play. Unless you are interested in adding [tag:performance] to this question, and taking it down that route, this feels like missing the forest for the trees. Yes, you can optimize this simple snippet of entirely untested code, but it is doubtful someone asking this level of question needs to be bombarded by "SIMD orgies".

Comment: Ignoring performance, best practices in C also involves not touching output parameters until the data to put in them is correct and calculated. That way we get rugged, reliable functions.